# Problema ao enviar algo para database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Então, estou tentando criar uma página, simples mesmo, para enviar algumas coisas para a database, (id,username,code_placa) porém não estou conseguindo, ao remover as linhas que dão erro, a página abre, porém, o botão de enviar apenas atualiza a página e não envia nada para a database, poderiam me ajudar? Erros que aparecem:

```
Warning: include(../../Templates/Hk_Head_2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/iceag061/public_html/hk/badges.php on line 2

Warning: include(../../Templates/Hk_Head_2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/iceag061/public_html/hk/badges.php on line 2

Warning: include(): Failed opening '../../Templates/Hk_Head_2.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php56/lib/php') in /home/iceag061/public_html/hk/badges.php on line 2

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in /home/iceag061/public_html/hk/badges.php on line 4
```

Código:

```
<?php
include "../../Templates/Hk_Head_2.php";

$query = $link->query('SELECT rank FROM usuarios WHERE username = "' .$username. '"');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
  $rangouser = $row['rank'];
}
if("$rangouser" == "2"){
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  exit;
}a
if("$rangouser" == "1"){
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  exit;
}
if("$rangouser" == "3"){
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  exit;
}
if("$rangouser" == "4"){
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  exit;
}

include "../../Templates/Hk_Nav.php";
?>

      <div class="container">
      <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
     <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading blue">
              <h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo $lang[426]; ?></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">

<div class="formulariohk">
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <label><?php echo $lang[418]; ?></label>
                    <input style="margin-bottom: 10px;" type="text" required="" class="form-control" name="id" placeholder="Id Da Placa" value="" />  <br>

                     <label><?php echo $lang[422]; ?></label>
                    <input style="margin-bottom: 10px;" type="text" required="" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Usuario" value="" />  <br>

                    <label><?php echo $lang[423]; ?></label><br>
                    <input style="margin-bottom: 10px;" type="text" required="" class="form-control" name="code_placa" placeholder="Codigo do emblema" value="" />  <br>

                    <center><input class="btn btn-primary" name="guardar" type="submit" value="<?php echo $lang[192]; ?>" style="width: 120px;" /></center>
                      </form>

                      <?php
if ($_POST['guardar'] && $_POST['titulo']) {
$enviar = "INSERT INTO usuarios_placas (id,username,code_placa) values ('".$username."','".strip_tags($_POST['id'])."','".strip_tags($_POST['username'])."','".$_POST['code_placa']."')";

if (@$link->query($enviar)) { 

// Guardar acci贸n en Logs si se ha iniciado sesi贸n

$fecha_log = date("Y-m-d");
$accion = $lang[434];
$enviar_log = "INSERT INTO logs (usuario,accion,fecha) values ('".$username."','".$accion."','".$fecha_log."')";
$link->query($enviar_log);
// Log guardado en Base de datos

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  location.href ="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>";
</script>
<?php
}
}
?>

</div></div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div><!-- /container -->

<?php 

include "../../Templates/Hk_Footer_2.php";

?>
```

Comment: Verifica o caminho do arquivo chamado no include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os três primeiros erros significa que o caminho ou nome dos arquivos estão incorretos, se você precisar de mais ajuda para resolver esse problema [edite sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/286789/edit) adicionando a estrutura das pastas do seu projeto

o 4° erro significa que a variável `$link` é nula, ou seja não existe a variável de conexão com o banco, para criar:

```
$link = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
```

Isso ocorre provavelmente porque as páginas que não estão sendo incluídas é aonde está sendo criada a conexão com o banco

**Dica:** em vez de usar um loop para guardar os dados:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $rangouser = $row['rank'];
}
```

Você pode usar a função [`fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) do mysqli:

```
$rangouser = mysqli_fetch_all($query);
```

Você ainda pode passar um segundo parâmetro:

- MYSQLI_ASSOC - retorna um array associativo
- MYSQLI_NUM - retorna um array numérico
- MYSQLI_BOTH - retorna uma única matriz com os atributos de ambas.

MYSQLI_BOTH é o valor padão

**Cuidado:** ao usar interpolação na declaração do SQL seu código está sujeito a [SQL Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864)

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema reside no fato de que seus includes estão sendo feitos da maneira errada.

Vejamos o seguinte exemplo:

```
index.php
 /includes/footer.php
```

se eu estiver em index.php para incluir o footer basta:

```
include 'includes/footer.php';
```

Se eu estiver em footer.php e quiser incluir o index:

```
include '../index.php';
```

Agora vamos para um cenário parecido com o seu:

```
index.php
 /includes/page/footer.php
```

se eu estiver em index.php para incluir o footer.php basta:

```
include 'includes/page/footer.php';]
```

Se eu estiver em footer.php e quiser incluir o index:

```
include '../../index.php';
```

O erro que aparece no seu código mostra claramente que o script não consegue encontrar os caminhos que você digitou para inclui-los. Bem não sei como está a sua organização de arquivos. Por isso não tenho como inferir muita coisa. Mas acho que se você tentar mudar esses parâmetros vais conseguir resolve-los.